# Audiokit: How record iphone 11 microphone with AKClipRecorder ? (CRASHED)

Tags: swift, audiokit

For the purpose of this issue , i edited the example/ios project of Audiokit: LoopbackRecording.

So  i  wanted to add effect before recording microphone:

```
let mic = AKMicrophone()
let reverb = AKReverb(mic)
reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.cathedral)
// Set up recorders
loopBackRecorder = AKClipRecorder(node: reverb)
```

This code is working fine on simulator (iphone 11 iOS13) but crashed on iPhone 11 Pro
when AudioKit trying to start showing this error log:

```
2020-02-17 13:49:05.854838+0100 LoopbackRecording[456:33365] [avae]
AVAudioEngine.mm:160   Engine@0x283c94f30: could not initialize, error = -10868
2020-02-17 13:49:05.955946+0100 LoopbackRecording[456:33365] [avae]
AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1397:Initialize: (err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain(ThisGraph, *GetInputNode())): error -10868
Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -10868.): file AudioKit-iOS/Examples/LoopbackRecording/LoopbackRecording/ViewController.swift, line 104
2020-02-17 13:49:05.967861+0100 LoopbackRecording[456:33365] Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -10868.)
```

I tried to debug and remove reverb and the app is still crashing, the AVFaudio code error :-10868 refer to this more explicite error: kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported

I found this error code catch only in one AudiokitFile: AUBuffer.cpp line 95:

```
...
if (format.IsInterleaved()) {
        nStreams = 1;
        channelsPerStream = format.mChannelsPerFrame;
    } else {
        nStreams = format.mChannelsPerFrame;
        channelsPerStream = 1;
        if (nStreams > mAllocatedStreams)
            COMPONENT_THROW(kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported);
    }
```

So i compared the format difference between the inputNode format of AudiokitEngine and the inputNode of mic.avAudioNode (AKMicrophone) :

```
(lldb) po AudioKit.engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
<AVAudioFormat 0x2803eaa80:  1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32>

(lldb) po AudioKit.engine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
<AVAudioFormat 0x2803dc0f0:  1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32>

(lldb) po mic?.avAudioNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
 <AVAudioFormat 0x2803e4190:  1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32>

(lldb) po mic?.avAudioNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
 <AVAudioFormat 0x2803dc1e0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>
```

I shall really appreciate any helps or tips that will allow me to debug this situation

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question and don't have an iPhone 11 Pro to test, but it sounds like its related to the microphone sample rate being 48Khz. This mismatch to the 44.1 of the output should be taken care of by AKMIcrophone, but apparently not.